# Compare arrays ios

Tags: iphone, ios, arrays, ipad

How to compare 2 arrays with different value
Array one has words en the other has images

Comment: What to compare with these two arrays? or you want to map these two arrays so that while dog is selected dog.jpg is displayed, Kindly explain..

Comment: it's something like that, when i press a button and the word dog is displayed than the image of the dog must also be displayed

Comment: Use one array.  You can easily get the name by taking the substring of the filename up to the period.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:array2 forKeys:array1];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the fully working code with your requirement, **can be used as an Idea** as you have images.

**Assuming your word and image are in same index**

I have just implemented similar kind of situation with strings named A.jpg, The idea is kept same, You need to transform accordingly.

```
NSMutableArray *words=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D", nil];
NSMutableArray *images=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"A.jpg",@"B.jpg",@"C.jpg",@"D.jpg", nil];

id selectedWord=@"C";//This is storing which word you have selected
id selectedImage=[images objectAtIndex:[words indexOfObject:selectedWord]];//this will store the image
NSLog(@"%@",selectedImage);//now you can display the image in imageview
```

## If words and images are not in anyorder

```
//words array is of no use, you can simply find which word you selected by extracting before "." , but as I am not aware of exact requirement I have left words array.
NSMutableArray *words=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D", nil];
NSMutableArray *images=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"B.jpg",@"D.jpg",@"C.jpg",@"A.jpg", nil];

id selectedWord=@"B";

NSInteger indexOfSelectedWord;
for (NSString *imageName in images) {

    if ([[[imageName componentsSeparatedByString:@"."]objectAtIndex:0]isEqualToString:selectedWord]) {
        indexOfSelectedWord=[images indexOfObject:imageName];
    }
}

id selectedImage=[images objectAtIndex:indexOfSelectedWord];

NSLog(@"%@ & %@",selectedWord ,selectedImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use an `NSDictionary`. This is how you do that (using the new Objective C literal syntax)

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{
        @"dog" : @"dog.jpg", 
        @"apple" : @"apple.jpeg",
        @"clown" : @"clown.gif"
};
```

To retrieve the image filename for "dog" from this dictionary do this:

```
NSString *fileName = dictionary[@"dog"];
```

Answer (score 0):

When a button is clicked you can simply take that value and search into images array to get the matching image name for e-g,

```
NSString *selValue = @"dog";
for (NSString *obj in imagesArray) {
    if ([obj rangeOfString:selValue].location != NSNotFound) {
        NSString *imageName = obj;
        break;
    }
}
```