# How to change section order in UITableView with Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have an UITableView with sections, and the NSDictionary is defined like that :

```
myTable = @{@"Category" : @[@"Home", @"News"],
            @"Useful links" : @[@"Tuning", @"Favorite"],
            @"Other" : @[@"About]};
```

And when I run the app, the "Other" section comes before "Useful links", I would like to rearrange section order, how can I do that?

Thanx guys

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856118/compare-arrays-ios

Comment: Are you ordering the keys and then generating sections or taking the dictionary keys as-is?  If you want to guarantee an ordering, use an NSArray of 3 dictionaries (each with 1 key) instead of an NSDictionary of 3 keys.